# Android add Text to Canvas fail

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am going to create a jpeg by drawing. The element is a text and a image. When it comes to the implementation,  only image and background color is drawn but there is no text. I have no diea what happens actually even I have called canvas.drawText

The below is my code

```
String folderName = "droidCanvas";
                String textString ="Hello , I am user 12345. \n Below is my signature.";
                String fileNameString = "test.jpg";
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()  + File.separator   + folderName );
                if(!folder.exists()){
                    folder.mkdir();
                }

            File bmpFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()  + File.separator   + fileNameString );
            if(!bmpFile.exists()){
                try {
                    bmpFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //Draw something
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED); 

            Paint txtPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

            txtPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
            txtPaint.setTextSize(20);
            bmpBase = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(bmpBase);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawCircle(w/2, h/2, 300, paint);
            canvas.drawText(textString ,w/2, 0 , txtPaint);

            //Export to jpeg
            try
            {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(bmpFile);
                bmpBase.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                fos = null;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fos != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fos.close();
                        fos = null;
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: try `canvas.drawText(textString ,w/2, h/2 , txtPaint);` and you will be able to at least see the text. Then you can re-position it later. Right now it is being drawn but you can't see it because its at extreme top center and out of bounds.

Comment: I see ... thanks , how about putting at the top left corner of the picture ? it seems easy to shoot outside the frame provided

Comment: You want to place text at top left corner? Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `canvas.drawText(textString ,w/2, h/2 , txtPaint);` and you will be able to at least see the text. Then you can re-position it later. Right now it is being drawn but you can't see it because its at extreme top center and out of bounds.

If you want to place it on top left corner then do this:

```
canvas.drawText(textString ,0 , txtPaint.getFontSpacing(), txtPaint);
```